# The notion of a point of vanishing mean oscillation is more general than that of Lebesgue points.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, bmo-martingales

How can I demonstrate that the notion of a vanishing mean oscillation point (VMO) is more general than a Lebesgue point?

The point $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a **Lebesgue point** if:

$$ \lim_{r\to 0} \oint_{B_r(y)} |f(x)-f(y)|\;  dx = 0 $$

The point $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a **VMO point** (vanishing mean oscillation) if:

$$ \lim_{r\to 0} \oint_{B_r(y)} |f(x)-(f)_{y,r}|\;  dx  = 0 $$

Here $\oint_U f=\frac{1}{|V|}\int_V f$ is the average integral of $f$ (I don't know the command in LateX to write an integral with a dash in the middle).
And $(f)_{y,r} = \oint_{B_r(y)}$.

---

I tried to put the limit inside the integral. But I can't see that it generalizes.

Some references

VMO1: p. 2 of https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-207-00/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3.pdf

VMO 2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation

Lebesgue point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point

Comment: Since the phrase "vanishing mean oscillation point" is NOT in the Wikipedia article you cited (in fact, even the shorter phrase "mean oscillation point" does not appear in it), I did a google search for "vanishing mean oscillation point". I got a total of 3 hits, one of which is this question and another is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.07257.pdf) which has what I believe you want at the top of p. 11, **(continued)**

Comment: where an example is given such that $R$ (set of Lebesgue points; this notation conflicts with the usage of $R$ in the proof of Lemma 4.6, by the way) is a **proper subset** of $J_c$ (set of VMO points). For where $R$ and $J_c$ are defined, see the 3 lines immediately above (4.19) on p. 10.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I did not find this paper.

Comment: *I did not find this paper* --- Although I've **dealt with** Lebesgue density notations a bit, and I **know a little about** Lebesgue points, and I've **heard a lot** about BMO (in connection with [papers involving porous set notions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22porous+set%22+%22BMO%22&filter=0)) but otherwise **I know essentially nothing** about BMO, I suspect it was an extreme stroke of luck that using a google search for the specific phrase you wrote led me to it.

Comment: Yes that's right. You're right. I've already spent a lot of time looking for this or any next idea.

Comment: If i understand correctly, if $f$ is VMO at $x$, and we change $f$ on a set of measure $0,$ it is still VMO at $x.$ But a Lebesgue point $x$ can be destroyed by redefining $f$ at just $x.$.

Comment: If you show your effort and write down the definitions and the actual implication that interests you, there's a better chance someone (e.g. me) can help you.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz: I put the definitions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the  Lebesgue differentiation Theorem we know that:

$$ \lim_{r\to 0+}\left(\frac{1}{|B_r(y)|}\int_{B_r(y)} f(x)\, dx \right) = f(y)\; a.e \; y\in \mathbb{R}^n $$

Then

$$ \oint_{B_r(y)} |f(x)-(f)_{r,y} |\; dx \leq \oint_{B_r(y)} |f(x)-f(y)|\, dx + \oint_{B_r(y)} |f(y)-(f)_{r,y} | \to 0$$

Where the first installment of the sum goes to 0 if $y$ is a Lebesgue point and the second, is the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem above.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\avint{\mathop{\rlap{\raise.15em{\scriptstyle --}}\kern-.13em\int}\nolimits}$
If $y$ is a Lebesgue point, it is easy to see that $f_{y,r} \to f(y)$ when $r \to 0$:
\begin{align}
|f_{y,r} - f(y)| 
&= \left| \avint_{B_r(y)} f(x) dx - f(y) \right| \\
&= \left| \avint_{B_r(y)} \left( f(x) - f(y) \right) dx \right| \\
& \leqslant \avint_{B_r(y)} |f(x) - f(y)| dx \\
&\to 0.
\end{align}

By triangle inequality, $y$ also satisfies the vanishing mean oscillation condition:
\begin{align}
\avint_{B_r(y)} |f(x) - f_{y,r}| dx 
&\leqslant \avint_{B_r(y)} |f(x)-f(y)| dx + \avint_{B_r(y)} |f_{y,r}-f(y)| dx \\
&\leqslant \avint_{B_r(y)} |f(x)-f(y)| dx + |f_{y,r}-f(y)| \\
&\to 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Michal for the answer. Could you be so kind as to clarify a passage please? How to pass the limit into the integral, since the integral is in the ball of radius r and the limit is in r -> 0?

Comment: OK, I included all calculations.